# didSelectRowAtIndex not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a `UITableView`with custom `UITableViewCell` this is the structure of my cell

[image]

I have disabled the userinteraction of every `UIButton` except the corner red button (Btn Delete). My problem is `didSelectRowAtIndex` delegate not firing.Data loading is happening also I have set the delegate from code.

Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSIndexPath *previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath;
if (indexPath == selectedIndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = nil;
} else {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
NSMutableArray *indexPaths=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSIndexPath *previous=previousIndexPath;
[indexPaths addObject:previous];
NSIndexPath *current=selectedIndexPath;
[indexPaths addObject:current];
if ([indexPaths count]>0) {
    [_tblPendings reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

}

Comment: Have you set the tableView delegate with your viewController.

Comment: yeas I have done it

Comment: What does your delegate method look like?

Comment: I update the question with my delegate

Comment: Are you touching the cell or the red button? A UIButton will intercept the touch, causing `didSelectRowAtIndex` to not be called.

Comment: my red button has another event,, but when I tap outside the red button it should fire the cell delegate

Comment: Have you confirmed the selection style of the cell? You want to make sure it's not `UITableViewSelectionStyleNone`. You can set it with `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewSelectionStyleDefault`.

Comment: cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault; I set this in cell for row at index but still same

Comment: @NiravD I checked,, but I dont see anything like that

Comment: Have you accidentally set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` for the `UITableView`, `UITableViewCell` or `UITableViewCell.contentView`? Or are you explicitly implementing the method `tableView:shouldSelectCellAtIndexpath:`?